Conditions of kosher meat prior to slaughtering
What are the considerations regarding the conditions in which animals are kept prior to shechita on kosher farms, and how do these conditions impact the kashrus of the meat? Specifically, how do factors such as confinement, handling, and overall welfare of the animals influence the assessment of whether the meat can be deemed kosher according to halacha?

related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/74079/caged-hens-and-other-seemingly-cruel-farming-methods/74082#74082

related: Can 'cruelty to animals' render an animal not kosher?

I don't know of any "kosher farms". Most farms are owned by non-jews and the slaughter houses purchase the animals they will shecht from those farms

Most kosher beef is sourced from the same farms that non kosher beef comes from. The shochtim go to a corner of the non kosher slaughterhouse and shecht there. If the animal is unfit, they hang it up on the regular conveyer belt. The back halves are also put back on the regular production line.
The kosher cows go through the same level of care the non kosher cows go through but the individuals that received less abuse on the farm (or are more resilient or better kept) are less likely to have disqualifying ailments.
There is a bit of self correction against abuse built into the biology of the animal but mistreatment doesn't make an animal not kosher (with the possible exception of having sex with it).

Interesting, I didn't know that's how it worked.
